# How to pass ajax value to controller

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a form that is inside foreach and I want to pass data-order-id="{{ $user->order_id }}" to the controller. My problem is that the value of data-order-id is displayed in console.log perfectly fine, but it is null in controllers when calling the variable.

blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('seller_order_all') }}" id="getID" method="post">
        @csrf
        
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column toggle-action" id="{{ $user->order_id }}-{{ $user->product_name }}-{{ $user->status }}" style="position: relative; border: 0.5px solid #8D8D8D; padding-left: 5px; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: -92px; width: 124.075px; background: #ffffff;">
        @if ($user->status == 'To Pay')
            <button class="btn to-pay-button" name="OrderStatus" value="To Pay" type="submit" data-order-id="{{ $user->order_id }}" style="padding: 0px; text-align: left; padding-bottom: 0px; font-size: 15px;">To Ship</button>
                                                            
        @endif
        @if ($user->status == 'To Ship')
            <button  utton class="btn to-pay-button" name="OrderStatus" value="To Ship" type="submit" data-order-id="{{ $user->order_id }}" style="padding: 0px; text-align: left; padding-bottom: 0px; font-size: 15px;">Shipping</button>
    
        @endif
        @if ($user->status == 'Shipping')
            <button class="btn to-pay-button" type="submit" name="OrderStatus" value="Completed" data-order-id="{{ $user->order_id }}"  style="padding: 0px; text-align: left; padding-bottom: 0px; font-size: 15px;">Completed</button>
            <button class="btn to-pay-button" type="submit" name="OrderStatus" value="Failed Delivery" data-order-id="{{ $user->order_id }}" style="padding: 0px; text-align: left; padding-bottom: 0px; font-size: 15px;">Failed Delivery</button>
        @endif   
    </div>
</form>
```

JS/AJAX:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $('.to-pay-button').click(function(event) {
        
        // Get the order_id from the data-order-id attribute of the clicked button
        var orderId = $(this).data('order-id');
        console.log("orderId: " + orderId);
        
        // Send the orderId to the server using an AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route('seller_order_all') }}',
            data: {
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                order_id: orderId,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Handle the response here
                console.log(response);
                
         
            },
            error: function(error) {
                // Handle any errors that occur during the AJAX request
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Controller:
I have (Request $request) and ::match(['post','get']).

$getOrder has a value.
$orderId is null.

```
if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $getOrder = $request->input('OrderStatus');
            $orderId = $request->input('order_id');            

            dd($getOrder, $orderId);
            

        }
```

Comment: You are submitting twice. Your form submiting function because of that you cannot take order_id, if you make button type button you can submit with javascript and you will see the order_id

Comment: It worked, Thank you! I have one more question, can I see the result in realtime without refreshing the page?

Comment: fyi, if that form is inside a loop you'll get multiple `id="getID"` - which is invalid, `id`s must be unique

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just set an ID so I can manually submit the JavaScript.

Comment: if you send return response()->json(["data" => "your_data_here"]); after you can take it from success response.data